# Calculated column that shows if column contains slicer value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get a PowerBI slicer to show only the data that matches a substring.

The Slicer; which is pulled from a different table than the main dataset.  (also I've created a Measure to tell me what value is selected.)

[image]

A data snipped below.  For instance if I select "CONS" only the highlighted data should appear as it contains the string CONS based on the active Measure (slicer value).

[image]

However it seems my calculated column **"isDisc"** always returns 1.  I've tried FIND, SEARCH, and CONTAINSSTRING all with the same results (everything is always true or 1).

this is the formula for "isDisc"

```
isDisc = FIND('Data Literacy'[Measure 2],'Data Literacy'[Target Discipline])
```

I'm not sure what fundamental concept I am missing, but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use measure instead of CalculatedColumn. CalculatedColumn and CalculatedTable are calculated once at refresh time.

```
OnlySelected = 
var __slicer = SELECTEDVALUE('Tabela 2'[Target Discipline])
var __currentRow = SELECTEDVALUE(Test1[Target Discipline])
return
IF( find( __slicer, __currentRow,1,FALSE()),1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks.  I tried your suggestion and still get "1s" throughout. I've pasted a screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/ipKlHaK

Comment: Did you create a measure or calculated column?

Comment: *facepalm* you are correct. Thank you! Works now.